# Give an example of subgroup of $G$ generated by $A?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have some  confusion on Dummit and foote Book  -Page no $: 62$

It is written that

> If $A$ is any subset of  the group $G$ define $$\langle A \rangle =\bigcap_{A\subseteq H , H\le G} H$$ .This is called the subgroup  of $G$ generated by $A$

My question :Give an example of the above definition ?

**My attempt** : I take $G= \mathbb{Z}_4$ , $A= \mathbb{Z_2}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_3$

$$\langle A \rangle =\bigcap_{A\subseteq H , H\subseteq G} H$$

$$\langle \mathbb{Z}_2 \rangle  =  \bigcap \mathbb{Z}_3$$

Element of $\mathbb{Z_3}$ are $0,1$ and $2$

$$\implies \langle \mathbb{Z}_2 \rangle =\{0\} \cap \{1\}\cap \{3\}$$

Is it true ?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. ”Give an example of the above definition?” says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: You seem to be labouring under the delusion that $\Bbb Z_2\subseteq \Bbb Z_4$  and $\Bbb Z_3<\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: ${\bf Z}_2$ is not a subset of ${\bf Z}_4$.

Comment: @jjagmath i edited

Comment: @GerryMyerson sir then what  will be the subset ?

Comment: You can take ${\bf Z}_4$ to be the set $G=\{\,0,1,2,3\,\}$ **with the operation of addition modulo four**, and you can take $A=\{\,0,1\,\}$ to be a subset of $G$, but then the only subgroup of $G$ containing $A$ is $G$ itself, so you'll have $H=G$ in that case.

Comment: A slightly more interesting example would be to take the same $G$, with $A=\{\,2\,\}$. Then $H=\{\,0,2\,\}$.

Comment: Or take $G$ to be the integers, under addition, and $A=\{\,6,10\,\}$. Then $H$ is the even integers.

Comment: While that definition is absolutely correct, I don't think that's the best way to think about generated subgroups. The best way to build a generated subgroup (at least for small examples) is to start with your set $A$ and find which elements from $G$ you need to include so you get a group structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is supposed to be a subset of $G$, here $G$ has elements $\{\overline 0, \overline 1 , \overline 2, \overline 3\}$ and $A$ should be a subset of that set, so for example it could be $\{ \overline 0 , \overline 2\}$.

Then the family of all of the subgroups $H$ that contain $A$ depends only on $A$ and you don't need to "select" $H$. In this example the subgroups that $H$ takes on would be $\{\overline 0, \overline 2\}$ and $\{\overline 0, \overline 1 , \overline 2, \overline 3\}$. Therefore the intersection of all of them would be $\{ \overline 0, \overline 2\}$, so in this case $\langle A \rangle = A$. This particular situation arises if and only if $A$ is already a subgroup.